# specify key values for return $query->fetchArray()?

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, doctrine-1.2, dql

Using Doctrine, I'm doing a query kinda like this:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('id,name')->from('people');
return $query->fetchArray();
```

It returns an object similar to the following array of arrays:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "34"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "John"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "156"
    ["name"]=>
    string(6) "Bob"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "27"
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "Alex"
  }
}
```

Notice how the array's keys count up from 0, 1, 2, etc? My question: Is it possible to specify where you want the key values to come from? For example, I would like the key values in the above case to be 34, 156 and then 27.

I noticed in the Doctrine doc's that both `fetchArray()` has parameters that you can feed them, but it doesn't say anything about what those parameters are...

```
public array fetchArray(string params)
```

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_query.html#fetchArray()

Also, I can obviously just repopulate a new array with the prefered key/value combinations, but I'm trying to avoid the extra processing required.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [INDEXBY](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language%3aindexby-keyword/en) DQL keyword.

Try something like:

```
<?php
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
           ->select('p.id,p.name')
           ->from('people p INDEXBY p.id');
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! Also I found the `Doctrine_Collection->setColumnKey()` method but it did not seem to do anything.